# Removing the focus from WPF TextBox causes performance to slow down

Tags: wpf, performance, textbox

A TextBox inside a Canvas; The Canvas is inside a ScrollViewer; The user could pane the Canvas with a mouse click down like GoogleMap. The problem is, after removing focus from the TextBox in code behind (programmatically) by `Keyboard.ClearFocus()` suddenly everything gets slow down and panning or other changes become very laggy. The performance goes to normal again if the user clicks on the Canvas or on another TextBox. By using Performance Profiler I couldn't find anything related to my code; only 16.79 percent of the performance is consumed with my code and the rest is on [External Code].
How could one find out what is the External Code that consumes this much of performance and why removing focus programmatically from a TextBox causes this drop-down of performance?

Before click on the Canvas

[image]

After click on the Canvas

[image]

Comment: Application Timeline may show you more usable data.

Comment: Also go to: Options -> Debugger -> Output Window and change everything to All. Maybe you'll find some surprises there.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski Thanks. Suggestions were helpful but couldn't provide any  specific information about the **External Code** part. In both cases of a **TextBox** being focused or the focus being removed programmatically, the **Application Timeline** shows identical values for **Layout** and **Render**. Maybe the WPF team should consider it as a bug.

Comment: They won't, until you provide a reproducible example. And if you do, please post it here first.

Comment: Oh, as a workaround try to name the canvas, and instead of calling `ClearFucus`, set focus on the canvas. That may work, as you wrote that clicking on canvas stops the high CPU consumption

Comment: Tried both, no change. Setting focus on another TextBox worked. Thank you for suggestions. Maybe I'll provide a workable example for them and here.